# Using GitHub, how do I enable the function that requires me to login every time I push

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, collaboration

I am new to github and am beginning to use it.

I would like to know how to have GitHub require me to login to the remote repo server whenever I push out some new code. On my personal computer it is fine, but one some other computers which I use a lot and share with othe people, I want to have some more security so no one else messes with my github.

I was required to log in when I first added the first repo from the source (bitbucket), after that I no longer had to enter in my username and password.

Is there any way to make me enter in my login information every time I want to push? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using an ssh url for your bitbucket repo? (and an https one for GitHub?)

Comment: I am using SSL/HTTPS for both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check (`git config -l`) if there is a credential helper that you could then remove:

```
git config --local --remove-section credential
```

And make sure that you have `git config core.askpass true`.